# Jira Cloud: How can I use JQL to return open Bugs linked to a Test Scenario ticket from Phase 1 of testing but not linked to a ticker from Phase 2?

Tags: jira, jql

My company is currently transitioning ERP systems and using Jira to track the project. We are about to enter phase 2 (P2) of testing and we want to be able to build a query in regular JQL (sadly no ScriptRunner add on) that would return open Bug tickets linked to a Test Scenario issue where affected version is Phase 1 (P1) but not linked to a scenario where the affected version is P2. Is there a way to do this? Even with a workaround such as creating a filters that that get used in the query would be fine. I am just hoping there is some way to do it.

Thanks in advance!